# NW.js not playing vimeo videos

Tags: html5-video, node-webkit

My nw.js app wraps an existing website, and im facing issues with videos from vimeo and vine etc. 
Youtube will play fine, but vimeo throws this error "This video can’t be played with your current setup.".

Ive googled alot and found two potential dealbreakers:
1) hardware acceleration in chromium has a reputation for breaking vimeo.
2) Ffmpeg and proprietary codecs are not bundled with nw.js due to licencing issues.

Can anyone confirm wether or not vimeo is working on your nw.js builds?  I dont know if i'm capable of rebuilding ffmpeg, it will take me a whole lot of time getting into, so want to verify if it will work before i get into it.

Heres my package.js:

```
    {
  "name": "helloworld",
  "version": "0.0.1",
    "user-agent" : "Testapplication",
  "main": "https://my.externalpage.com",
  "chromium-args": "--disable-accelerated-video --disable-accelerated-video-decode --allow-outdated-plugins",
  "window": {
    "title": "test",
    "icon": "myicon.png",
    "toolbar": true,
    "frame": true,
    "width": 1920,
    "height": 1080,
    "position": "center",
    "min_width": 400,
    "min_height": 200
  },
  "webkit": {
    "plugin": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to track down a pre-compiled version of ffmpeg-sumo which fixed all the videoplayers, so that seems to be the issue for sure. Thanks, google!